Por que mis alertas no se muestran correctamente en angular 18?
Estoy realizando una aplicación en angular con al siguiente estructura

componente de alertas (alert.component.ts)
componente dode invoco una alerta (login.component.ts)
servicio donde gestiono la logica de las alertas( alert.service.ts)
componente principal donde mando a llamar las alertas (app.component.ts)

Mi logica es la siguiente desarrolle un componente de alertas personalizado con tailwind donde este componente solo lo implementare una vez en el componete principal
app.html
    <app-alert></app-alert>

<div class="w-full h-screen">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

mi idea es colocarlo aqui una sola vez y pueda ser llamado de manera global por toda la aplicación mediante el alert.service.ts
este alert.service lo invoque dentro de mi login.component.ts
al momento de hacer el login, inyecte el servicio de alertas
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    // AlertComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AlertService
  ],
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrl: './login.component.css'
}) 
 constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private alertService: AlertService
  ) {
    this.loadData.company = '"Tu compañia"';
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      user: ['', [Validators.required]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

Parte relevante de la implementacion de alert.service.ts
  if (response.status === 'success' && response.data) {
            this.isLoginSuccessful = true;
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
          } else {
            this.isLoginSuccessful = false;
            this.alertService.showAlert('Usuario o contraseña incorrectos', 'error');
             this.errorMessage = response.message || 'Error desconocido';

          }

Anexo codigo de mi alert.service.ts
    export class AlertService {
  private isShowAlert = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private alertMessage = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  private typeSource = new BehaviorSubject<'success' | 'error' | 'warning' | 'info'>('info');
  public message$ = this.alertMessage.asObservable();
  public type$ = this.typeSource.asObservable();
  public isVisible$ = this.isShowAlert.asObservable();

  constructor(
  ) { }

  showAlert(message: string, type: 'success' | 'error' | 'warning' | 'info'): void {
    console.log("1.-Entra el servicio")
    this.alertMessage.next(message);
    this.typeSource.next(type);
    this.isShowAlert.next(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.hideAlert();
    }, 5000);
  }

  hideAlert(): void {
    this.isShowAlert.next(false);
  }

  closeAlert(): void {
    this.hideAlert();
  }
}

y por ultimo el codigo de mi alert.component.ts, en esta parte ya probe implementando observables y directamente en mi html usando Pipe async pero de igual forma no detecta los cambios al mandar a llamar el servcio desde mi login.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-alert',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './alert.component.html',
  styleUrl: './alert.component.css',
  providers: [
    AlertService,
  ],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ],
})
public title: string = '';
  // isShowAlert$!: Observable<boolean>;
  // message$!: Observable<string>;
  // type$
  private alertService = inject(AlertService);
  isShowAlert$ = false;
  message$ = '';
  type: 'success' | 'error' | 'warning' | 'info' = 'info';


  ngOnInit(): void {
  
      this.alertService.isVisible$.subscribe(
        (state) => (this.isShowAlert$ = state),
      );

    this.alertService.message$.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data)
      this.message$ = data

    });
    this.alertService.isVisible$.subscribe((show) => {
      console.log(show)
      this.isShowAlert$ = show

    });

    this.alertService.type$.subscribe((type) => {
      console.log(type)
      this.type = type

    });
  }

Investigue y para esta sutuacion es necesario implementar BehaviorSubject sin emabargo no he tenido éxito
Notas importantes
Algo que me di cuenta fue de que mi component alert.component.ts se renderiza una sola vez ya que al estar a nivel de app.html se carga también y hace los subscribes que tengo definidos en el alert.component.ts pero solo la primera vez, ya renderizado no vuelve a detectar los cambios también implemente directamente en el servicio forzarlos con ChangeDetectorRef con ayuda de chatgpt pero no tuve exito tampoco
Actualizacion
Me recomendaron agregar el codigo de un playground, anexo el link para que puedan visualizar el proyecto de mejor forma y el problema que hay de las alertas
Nueva Actualización
El link no lo publique de manera coreecta anexo el correcto
https://stackblitz.com/github.com/Israeldelira/angular-18-alerts

Angular no lo toco desde la v4, así que no puedo ayudarte. Hoy trabajo con Blazor el cual tiene un paradigma muy similar. Y cuando me enfrenté con el tema de las Alertas vi lo mismo que veo en tu código, que es una brutalidad de elementos que hay que hacer para levantar un simple cuadro con un mensaje!!! una locura!!.  Al final lo que hice (y no me arrepiento) es que me llevé la alerta para fuera, la hice directamente en JS puro en una función global, porque para mí una alerta es algo global no un servicio (el equivalente a una función estática).

Si pienso que si debe de ser algo global sin embargo me gustaria trabajarlo con typescript y no implementar js en esta parte, igual muchs gracias por tu comentario, la verdad si para ser algo simple si es muy complejo

podrías preparar un playground de tu código? yo no veo la necesidad de usar subjects ni observables. Me da la impresión de que la alerta se muestra pero simplemente no se ve por css, quizás queda detrás de la página, quizás ponerle z-index: 10000 a tu alert

Claro, tienes razón en un momento lo genero y lo actualizo en la pregunta, pero en cuanto a lo del z-index:1000 lo probare pero lo raro es de que cuando la fuerzo si me la muestra al inicio sin embargo mas bien parece que no detecta los cambios de el menssage y isShowAlert

@input() y OnChanges puede ser una solución simple

@aloMalbarez el detalle con esa forma me funciona correctamente pero tendria que implementar el  en todas las vistas que quisiera renderizar y solo quiero mandarlo a llamar desde el app.html una sola vez y de manera dinamica mostrar y ocultar mediante rxjs (behaviorsubjects o alguna otra solucion)

I have no time to build a complete answer. but this tutorial might help you :). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gO8rL5iXk-Y

Hice pruebas locales con tu código del siguiente enlace:
https://github.com/Israeldelira/angular-18-alerts
Y logré hacerlo funcionar eliminando los providers de AlertService en los siguientes archivos:

alert.component.ts
login.component.ts

A continuación, te muestro los cambios realizados:
En alert.component.ts:

@Component({
  selector: 'app-alert',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './alert.component.html',
  styleUrl: './alert.component.css',
  // providers: [
  //   AlertService,
  // ], // remover o comentar estas lineas
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ],
})

En login.component.ts:

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  // providers: [AlertService], // remover o comentar esta linea
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrl: './login.component.css'
})

Explicación:
El AlertService está creado con providedIn: 'root', lo que significa que Angular lo proporciona a nivel global, es decir, una única instancia de AlertService estará disponible en toda la aplicación. No es necesario agregarlo como proveedor en cada componente. Si lo haces, no estarías utilizando una instancia diferente para cada componente, sino que Angular crearía un nuevo proveedor de AlertService en ese componente específico, lo que puede generar comportamiento inesperado.

